# Scale predicted probability in logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, classification, multiple-regression

I am trying to

1) classify a bunch of [0,1] ratios into two groups  Group 0: Ratio = 0, Group 1: Ratio != 0.

2) predict the actual response with multiple predictors in R.

My question would then be:

Q1: Can I use the scaled predicted probability as the predicted response?

Q2: Should I classify the group before the regression before running the regression to solve the warning message? Would the data structure/predicted be affected?

I thought of achieving Goal 1 and Goal 2 separately but I can't seem to find a way to fit a unbalanced [0,1] non-censored data with good prediction.

---

Basically my response is something like this

```
y<-c(rep(0,100),0.3,0.4,0.8,1.0)
x<-cbind(rnorm(104,20,2),as.factor(c(rep(0,90),rep(1,5),rep(0,8),rep(1,1)))
,as.factor(sample(c(1:3),104,TRUE,prob = c(0.6,0.3,0.1))))

data<-data.frame(cbind(y,x))
```

and y is strictly between 0 to 1.

I then fit it with a logistic regression and get the predicted probability:

```
fit<-glm(y~.,data=data, family = "binomial")  
fit.prob<-predict(fit,type="response")
```

I used the probability to make classification model (Goal 1)

```
class<-y;class[y==0]="0";class[y!=0]="1"

cutoff<-0.06
fit.pred=rep(0,length(fit.prob)); fit.pred[fit.prob >=cutoff]=1
table(fit.pred,class)
```

However, I also want to predict y from new data set, this is probably wrong, but here's what I did

```
se<-fit.prob<-predict(fit,type="response",se=T)$se.fit
scaled.fit<-fit.prob/max(fit.prob)
scale.fit.UL<-scaled.fit+1.96*se
scale.fit.LL<-scaled.fit-1.96*se
```

and I used this to be the prediction interval for y. Is there any other way to do it other than this?

Comment: What exactly are the y-values? They certainly aren't Bernoulli (yes/no) data. You call them "ratios"; what are they ratios of? In the example, they seem to occur only at fixed values, is that true of the real / full data?

Comment: they are x/(x+y) kind of ratio, so it is continuous on [0,1]. But most of the values for x is 0, resulting a lot of zeros in the ratios. My main goal is to classify those x = 0 group and to predict that x/(x+y) number given a testing data.

Comment: What are the original x & y? Will they only ever occur at a few fixed values?

Comment: No they can be any positive number, X is amount spent, Y is account balance. The majority of 0 in response X/(X+Y) is due to few X > 0. I tried OLS on Y still didn't work.  If you are referring to the predictors, there are about 15 variables, some continuous, some counts, and one categorical.

Comment: So X & Y are in, say, dollars? How could someone end up w/ a ratio of 1? Can they spend money w/ nothing in the bank?

Comment: Yes, X and Y are in dollar. The model is for determining how much the bank can recover from a bad account, namely Pay/(Current loan balance+Pay). If they payoff everything it would be Pay/(0 + Pay ) = 1 or 100%   Therefore I want to 1) classify the accounts into "Pay account" and "no pay account", 2) predict recovery precent for the account.

Comment: Thanks, you should have included all of this at the outset. The question is largely uninterpretable w/o that info. "Pay" is a person's monthly net pay, and "balance" is the outstanding balance on the person's loan, is that right? So, when the ratio is 1, that is b/c they actually have no outstanding loan balance at all, & when it's 0, that is b/c they are (say) unemployed, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure forming a ratio in this way makes a lot of sense. Why not just predict how much cash you will get from each person? You could include pay as another predictor. Ie, you will predict a value of \$0 for people who have no money or don't owe anything, & a positive sum otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for responding fast. It is possible to predict cash from each person, but I suspect if assumption for linear regression will hold as it is a highly skewed data that can't be transformed (easily). (Pay + Loan) is also one of the original predictors too. I guess the question becomes how to do regression on a highly skewed data then? Or should I do a regression ON TOP of a classification to avoid the zero's?

Comment: You wouldn't be using linear regression; you'd use something like Gamma or a count regression model. Also, the idea of having pay & loan on both sides of the equation makes no sense. What is the dataset? Do you have a set of historical records w/ people, various covariates, & how much was ultimately recouped? How are you taking time into account, is it the amount recouped w/i a given interval? (I assume you can get more & more money from someone as time goes by.) Is there any censoring in the data?

Comment: Basically the team is trying to either sell those bad accounts or keep them. The value (Pay+Loan) is only used to back-date the balance at the time of decision (time t). The response value "Pay" is all the payment received after time t (only available for training data). My dataset is the historical data for those accounts with characteristics like loan type, loan terms and so. I doubt if count regression would work since my response is continuous.

Comment: Wait, is Pay how much they get paid (eg, whether or not they are employed), or how much they've paid the bank back on their loan? Above, I thought it was the former, now it sounds like the latter. I'm still not sure I can get a clear enough sense of your situation. A Gamma GLM is probably better, but you could round to the nearest dollar w/o really losing much information, I'd suspect.

Comment: Sorry if I confused you, its the latter. If I round to the nearest dollar and fit everything to a count model, I would have to do something like a zero-inflated model then? I am not too familiar with Gamma regression but R output "  non-positive values not allowed for the 'gamma' family " error when running gamma glm.

Comment: I gather you're talking about a hurdle model either way.

Comment: Hi gung, do you happen to know why "Error in solve.default(as.matrix(fit_count$hessian))" shows up while running hurdle() ? It works fine if I only run one covariate, but not with more than 1.

Comment: Funny... I was answering your question on ARIMA and had quite some text already, but you deleted the question...

Comment: @RichardHardy So sorry about that ... I am new to CV and thought I should delete an unanswered post ..

Comment: @RichardHardy I undeleted the [post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186164/armax-model-and-validation), I have learned more knowledge on the issues, see if you are still interested..

Comment: Why? That a post has failed to attract an answer does not necessarily mean there is anything wrong with the post. (Also, deleting posts may not be quite good, I think there is something in the framework of Stack Exchange that makes deleting a disadvantage for you.) If you can undelete it, I will post my answer (of course, if the question is still relevant).